# Python. Выполнение задач в определенное время, asyncio, aicron, aioschedule

Tags: python, asyncio

Стоит теоретическая цель, отсылать пользователю в телеграм сообщение в определенное (личное для каждого пользователя) время. Но я тут чтобы не захламлять, не буду подключать aiogram и т.д.

```
import asyncio
import aioschedule as schedule
import time
import aiocron


async def job(name): #Функция что должна выполниться
    print(f'Hello {name}')
    await asyncio.sleep(1) # не понимаю зачем это


@aiocron.crontab('*/1 * * * *', start=True)
def get_data():
    find_all = [{'name': 'Max', 'time': '14:49'}, {'name': 'Alex', 'time': '14:49'}, {'name': 'Jim', 'time': '14:50'}, {'name': 'Polina', 'time': '14:51'}]
    for a in find_all:
        time_from_list = a['time']
        name_from_list = a['name']
        # Задача на выполнение в конкретное время
        schedule.every().day.at(time_from_list).do(job, name=name_from_list)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
while True:
    loop.run_until_complete(schedule.run_pending())
    time.sleep(1)
#Эта строчка относится к крону
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Код более-менее рабочий, но есть проблемы и вопросы.

1. При запуске крона, задачи дублируются. То есть если запускать его раз в минуту, то за 10 минут, будет 10 задач на выполнение функции job c уникальным параметром.

Я пробовал убить процессы по-разному, прямо внутри функции get_data

```
loop.stop()
loop.close()
schedule.cancel_job(job)
schedule.clear()
```

Но ничего не выходит :( Запустить процесс внутри функции также не получается.

2. Это вообще нормальный вариант?

Обращение к БД будет конечно не раз в минуту, как щас выставлено, а гораздо реже.
Но если заданий будет создано под 1000 или больше, это нормально?

3. time.sleep(1) в while true

Это такая проверка на выполнение задания?

Буду благодарен за помощь и советы.

Comment: 'Я пробовал убить процессы по-разному' так не плодите и убивать не предется

Comment: 'задачи дублируются' Сделайте проверку запущена та или иная задача

Comment: @Сергей Шашко Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
find_all = [{'name': 'Max', 'time': '14:49'}, {'name': 'Alex', 'time': '14:49'},
            {'name': 'Jim', 'time': '14:50'}, {'name': 'Polina', 'time': '14:51'}]
for a in find_all:
    if schedule.get_jobs(a['name']) == []:
        schedule.every().day.at(a['time']).do(job, name=a['name']).tag(a['name'])
```